# How to solo-mine Aeon?

Tags: cpu-mining, aeon, solo-mining

Suppose one has the Aeon software built and installed, how does one then initiate solo-mining Aeon using the CPU?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want to have the target Aeon wallet open all the time (for security reasons, or you prefer to start mining at system startup non-interactively), you can also start solo CPU mining using the daemon itself. Example syntax (replace the placeholders with actual values obviously):

`aeond --start-mining <target-aeon-wallet-address> --mining-threads <number-of-CPU-threads>`

Finding the number of available CPU threads:

- On macOS, you can show the number of available threads with `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`.
- On Windows, you can see the number of available threads with the `msinfo32.exe` utility. In there, go to the "Processors" line, and note the number of "Logical Processors".

Once the daemon is active, you can enable and disable displaying the hash-rate with the `show_hr` and `hide_hr` commands. This is optional, mining still works if you don't show the hash rate.

When you're lucky to mine a block, you'll see something like this in the daemon logging:

```
2017-Jan-20 12:58:36.932824 [miner 0]Found block for difficulty: 224668625
```

Answer (score 7):

Sync your daemon. Open the wallet and type:

```
start_mining walletid threads
```

Replace walletid with your public wallet ID, and replace threads with the number of threads you are willing to dedicate to mining. Make sure that you do not put more threads than your processor has, or your mining speed may be impacted.