# I need a manual how to mine aeon with daemon

Tags: aeon, mining

Where can I find a manual or a guide that explains how to mine aeon with the daemon? What alternatives are there to mine aeon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solo-mine Aeon?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3623/how-to-solo-mine-aeon)

Answer (score 1):

Using the daemon you can solo mine, and it's quite simple. Just sync the daemon, open and sync your wallet, then type:

```
 start_mining <number of threads>
```

Except replace  with the number of threads you would like use, probably 2 or 4.

You can also do it without even starting the wallet, just the daemon as described here: [How to solo-mine Aeon?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3623/how-to-solo-mine-aeon/3626#3626)